# TextBlock does not grey out

Tags: c#, xaml, view, textblock

I need to grey out the a text block in my datagrid when "CandEdit" is false and i can't figure out why my code doesnt work...

what i tried:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Views:FilterDataGridColumn.CanFilter="True" MinWidth="80" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Alarms" Binding="{Binding Path=AlarmName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="{Binding Path=CanEdit}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextBlock` is not a intractable element, it can't be edited like a `TextBox`, so disabling it doesn't change it's appearance by deafult. You can just set it's font color to gray if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So is there a way for the textblock changes color when canEdit is false?

Comment: You could use a ReadOnly TextBoxColumn instead and toggle isenabled that way.

Comment: @Lynct I would make a `Trigger` that will change the `TextBlock` color according to `CanEdit`